# Given is the result of the model performance. Help me with this MCQ

Tags: machine-learning, training

You also evaluate your model on the test set, and find the following:

Human-level performance 0.1%
Training set error  2.0%
Dev set error   2.1%
Test set error  7.0%
What does this mean? (Check the two best options.)

1. You have underfit to the dev set.
2. You should get a bigger test set.
3. You should try to get a bigger dev set.
4. You have overfit to the dev set.

Answer (score 1):

I think answer are options **3)** and **4)**

Clearly there seems to be overfiting towards dev set as the dev set error is low and almost equal to training set error.

And  increasing the number of samples helps minimizing overfiting problem..

Comment: `And increasing the number of samples helps minimizing overfiting problem`. In that case don't you think the test set size should be increased?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer should be **2.)** and **4.)**. Since your training/dev set is performing well but the test set is not as good. Hence your model is overfitting to the training/dev set.

Also increasing the sample size of test set will help in bringing down this error.